# Font Awesome not loaded on first page of website only - divi theme

Tags: actions, homepage, wp-enqueue-style

I am new to WordPress and I created a WordPress website using DIVI theme, I have used font awesome on the website but unfortunately fonts are not loaded on first page of website only, I am getting 404 error on .woff and .woff2 file.

Link to website is [this](http://daewoo.com.pk/)

I have used this code in function.php to use fonts in website

```
function addFontsAwesome() {
 //echo "Does this output to the actual page?";
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css' );
}
add_action('wp_head', 'addFontsAwesome');
```

word press version : 4.7
Font Awesome version: latest

Any idea in this would be highly appreciated ?

Comment: First check that `.woff` and `.woff2` files exists or not. Then check your directory permissions where those files are. An secondly hoo the scripts to `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, not `wp_head`.

Comment: yes, file exists, I have tripled checked the folder. `wp_enqueue_scripts`  doesn't work also